# Is there a way to change partial text colour in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

while comparing 2 strings which I imported from `Excel`. The string 2 will contain certain text which is not present in string1 which needs to be highlighted in red. When i am exporting the updated coloured string back into excel I get theis as output rather than the coloured string

Snippet of the code used

```
df=Alteryx.read("#1")       
stringc=""
while i<len(stringa):
       
    if stringa[i].upper() ==stringb[ind].upper() :
        stringc=stringc+(Style.RESET_ALL+stringa[i])
    else:
        i=i-1
        stringc=stringc+ (Fore.RED +stringb[ind])
    i=i+1
    ind=ind+1

    
print(stringc)
df.loc[0][2]=stringc
                   
   
Alteryx.write(df,1)
```

Output:

```
x1b[0mS\x1b[0mu\x1b[0ms\x1b[0mt\x1b[0ma\x1b[0mi\x1b[0mn\x1b[0ma\x1b[0mb\x1b[0ml\x1b[0me\x1b[0m \x1b[0md\x1b[0me\x1b[0mv\x1b[0me\x1b[0ml\x1b[0mo\x1b[0mp\x1b[0mm\x1b[0me\x1b[0mn\x1b[0mt\x1b[0m \x1b[0mt\x1b[0ma\x1b[0mr\x1b[0mg\x1b[0me\x1b[0mt\x1b[0m \x1b[0m(\x1b[0me\x1b[0mn\x1b[0mv\x1b[0mi\x1b[0mr\x1b[0mo\x1b[0mn\x1b[0mm\x1b[0me\x1b[0mn\x1b[0mt\x1b[0ma\x1b[0ml\x1b[0m \x1b[0ma\x1b[0mn\x1b[0md\x1b[0m \x1b[0ms\x1b[0mo\x1b[0mc\x1b[0mi\x1b[0ma\x1b[0ml\x1b[0m)\x1b[0m \x1b
```

I am using `pandas` data frame for writing the output
Is there a way to rectify this

Comment: your question is unclear, please update with proper data.

Comment: I have added details and code snippet I hope its clear now